# Any recommendations for Sqlite C# ORM code generation

Tags: c#, sqlite, orm

Can anyone recommend an Sqlite C# ORM code generation tool.

I have found the Habanero framework, any comments on that?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have gone with Subsonic in this instance. To help anyone else out, here is a 'basic' example of creating a class and using Subsonic and Sqlite together.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using SubSonic;
using SubSonic.Schema;
using SubSonic.Repository;
using SubSonic.DataProviders;

namespace SubsonicSqliteTest
{
    public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid();

            // Set Defaults
            FirstName = String.Empty;
            LastName = String.Empty;
            Username = String.Empty;
            Password = String.Empty;
            IsAdministrator = 0;
        }

        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int IsAdministrator { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }

        public static User Get(Guid id)
        {
            string databasePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "Database.db");
            IDataProvider provider = ProviderFactory.GetProvider("Data Source=" + databasePath + ";Version=3;New=True;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1;", "System.Data.SQLite");
            var repository = new SimpleRepository(provider, SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);
            var users = from user in repository.All<User>()
                        where user.ID == id
                        select user;

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                return user;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public User Save()
        {
            string databasePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "Database.db");
            IDataProvider provider = ProviderFactory.GetProvider("Data Source=" + databasePath + ";Version=3;New=True;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1;", "System.Data.SQLite");
            var repository = new SimpleRepository(provider, SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);
            repository.Add(this);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Habanero looks too big for my requirements in this case. We do have our own framework which is also too heavy-weight and am in fact replacing it in this instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others have already posted about NHibernate (especially with [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/)) and ADO.Net Entity Framework which are both great.  You may also want to look at [SubSonic](https://github.com/subsonic).  If you are considering SQLite then your database requirements must be fairly simple and [SubSonic's SimpleRepository option](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Simple_Repo_5_Minute_Demo) is super easy to use.

Comment: Yes, my requirements are ver simple, just need a very lightweight datastore and would rather try sqlite than access.

Comment: The SubSonic SimpleRepository looks pretty good for small apps and quick proof-of-concepts! Any idea on how to connect a SimpleRepository to Sqlite DataProvider or how to configure an Sqlite connection string?

Comment: I am going to go with Subsonic SimpleRepository, thanks for the help. (I have included a basic class that demonstrates Sqlite and Subsonic in the Question)

Comment: Glad I could help out.  Looks like you found the connections string, right?

Answer (score 3):

Several .NET object-relational mappers support SQLite.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249550/what-orm-frameworks-for-net-do-you-like-best) a list of .NET ORMs: of the ones mentioned there, I know that [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) and [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/lightspeed/default.aspx) support SQLite, as does the Entity Framework does via the provider mentioned in [eWolf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934303/any-recommendations-for-sqlite-c-orm-code-generation/1934336#1934336).  I am not sure about others.

In terms of code generation, LightSpeed and the Entity Framework (via System.Data.SQLite) include tools for importing an existing SQLite database schema; I'm not sure about NHibernate.  (**Disclosure:** I work for the company that makes LightSpeed; trying to keep the answer factual though!)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is exactly what you're looking for; have you already seen this?

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

You can use it with ADO.NET 2.0 or the ADO.NET 3.5 Entity Framework.

Comment: This also looks good, just trying to connect SubSonic to this...

Comment: thanks, but link is dead

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework

you can also use the linq to sql magic thingy

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "LINQ to SQL magic thingy" only works with SQL Server.

Comment: im not... but it kinda sucks anyhow...
this helps?
http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Comment: LINQ to SQL is only for MSSQL server.  But, the Entity Framework gives you a strong LINQ provider so you can do basically the same stuff.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectStore.Sqlite works with SqLite pretty good too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very powerful ORM, generate the code friendly http://www.schematrix.com